# Некоторые настройки на вашем компьютере не позволяют Composer работать должным образом

Tags: composer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вопросе и есть ответ, нужно добавить расширение `php_openssl`.

Для начала нужно проверить в папке где стоят расширения для `php` (по умолчанию это `ext`) чтобы был файл `php_openssl.dll`.

Если есть файл `php.ini`, то найти и расскоментировать в нём строки:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll 
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Если не создавался `php.ini` (проверить можно в консоли `php -ini`), то взять к примеру `php.ini-development` и переименовать в `php.ini`.